# where can I " adb install "?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Ubuntu for developing my 1st android. I have a problem and the solution is  to `adb install DataAttach.apk` .

my problem is, where can i do `adb install DataAttach.apk`?

i tried this:

```
$ cd android-sdk-linux/
$ adb install DataAttach.apk

adb: command not found
```

do anyone can give me an idea about my case?

Comment: Have you actually installed the Android tools? Is adb installed, but not in your path? You have not provided sufficient information.

Comment: yes, i have installed the android tools... but i have no idea where can i `adb install DataAttach.apk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Open the terminal and move to android-SDK-Folder.
 2)Go to platform-tools.
 3)check for the existence of adb by using ls command
 4)then try using adb as shown below

```
 ./adb install project.apk
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the adb command to your $PATH variable.

On ubuntu, you should add these lines to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=(path to your android-sdk/folder)
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

and finally, restart your system, and that should work.